not able to detect the error im using node 20 facing error in next.js deployment through code deploy on ubuntu 22.04
not able to detect the error
I'm using node 20 and
facing an error in next.js deployment through code deploy
this is my appspec.yml
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/next/Frontend_Development/
    overwrite: true
    owner: root
    runas: root
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: /deploycommands.sh
      timeout: 1800
      runas: root

this is my file
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/next/Frontend_Development/
npm install &&
npm run build &&
pm2 restart dev-apowest

not able to detect the error
[stderr]
[stderr]SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
[stderr] at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
[stderr] at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
[stderr] at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
[stderr] at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
[stderr] at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
[stderr] at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
[stderr] at Module.mod.require (/home/next/Frontend_Development/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28)
[stderr] at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
[stderr] at Object.<anonymous> (/home/next/Frontend_Development/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:7:20)
[stderr] at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)

